# Auth0 Silent Authentication with Universal Login

Tags: auth0

I have two applications (not APIS), both are using Auth0 Universal Login.

Now if user is logged-in in one application, clicking on "navigation menu" of 2nd application should do the silent login in 2nd application.

According to the documentation, following url will do the trick

> https://atea-dev.eu.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id_1st_application}&state={dont_know}&redirect_uri={redirec_uri_2nd_application}&scope=openid+email&prompt=none

I have two questions here, how to get state and why this url still shows login page.

Can anybody help here, I am really stuck and cannot find exact example anywhere which have used universal login

Comment: The state is a random string and this should not show the login page (unless you're doing something wrong with the response). I suggest you try out the Auth0.js SDK, so it does this automatically for you, or have a look at an Auth0 quickstart on how to do this.

Comment: Its the universal login and two different applications need to be integrated together. Single application is working fine

Comment: This might need a bit more details about your stack, the kind of app, etc. I suggest starting a discussion at https://community.auth0.com and also checking out the docs: https://auth0.com/docs/sso/single-sign-on